# Emacs whitespace mode doesn't show ^M characters

Tags: newlines, whitespace-mode

Somebody in my team has checked in a file with MS-DOS line endings into the git repo. with vi's binary mode, `vi -b hello.py`, i can see lines ending with ctrl character - `^M`.

In emacs, whitespace-mode, the same characters are shown with `$` sign. I infer, emacs has changed `^M`/`$` chars uniformly to `$` chars.

How can i restrict emacs from converting windows line feed into unix line feed and rather show the line feed chars - `^M` in its original form and not as `$`?

I am trying to figure out, if git local repo can be configured to do this windows to unix line feed mapping, rather than emacs doing it.

Comment: Note that Emacs does not automatically *convert* from one EOL type to another. It will just recognise the EOL style for a given file (if it is consistent) and *display* the file as if that style was native.

Comment: What do you see in mode line? It should show current encoding, so if you're on Unix-like system, it will show `DOS` label. Do you see it? You can easily convert entire file into Unix EOL style with `C-x RET f` or `M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system`. Git can be scripted to perform such conversion automatically too, but this requires additional efforts. [See here for example](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `^M` is the carriage-return character, not the linefeed char (that one is `^J`.

Here is one answer for this part of your question: How to 
*show the line feed chars - ^M in its original form and not as $*:

1. By default, `^M` characters should be highlighted using face `escape-glyph`.  Are you sure this is what you are seeing?  Try customizing that face (`M-x customize-face`) to something more noticeable than the default coloring.

   If you do not see `escape-glyph` highlighting with your Emacs setup, try starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).  Now do you see this highlighting?

   If so, then recursively bisect your init file, to see which part of it introduces the problem. You can use command `comment-region` to comment out a selection of text, and `C-u` with that command to uncomment a selection.
2. You can also try using library [`highlight-chars.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/highlight-chars.el), which gives you more options for highlighting characters (any characters).  [Here](http://www.emacswiki.org/ShowWhiteSpace#HighlightChars) is more info about this library.

For the line-end conversion part of your question, have a look at the Emacs manual, node [Text and Binary](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-and-Binary.html).

Someone else can speak to how you might use GIT to perform the conversion automatically.

Comment: Drew, i installed `highlight-chars.el. when i run `hc-highlight-chars`, the minibuffer prompts `Chars to highlight`. How can i give the control character `^M` here. Since `C-v \n` that i use in vim, has got other bindings it seems

Comment: You can always insert a control character in Emacs using `C-q`. So you hit `C-q RET` (or `C-q C-m`). See the Emacs manual, node [Inserting Text](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html). The key `RET` (or `C-m`) is itself bound to a command, so it is not self-inserting in the minibuffer (or in most other contexts, for that matter).